# Using Google OAuth in Angular 12 with @angular/fire@^7.0.0 firebase@^9.0.0

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angular12

After imports angular/file modules in `app.module.ts`

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I manage Auth services on a lazy featured module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I wrote an article about it: [Angular 12 with Firebase 9](https://code.build/p/LWmSi3HfQzu5TMKPzb5p6i/angular-12-with-firebase-9)

---

I don't think they've updated their docs yet. I had to figure it out by trial and error:

**app.module.ts**

```js
provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import {
  Auth,
  signOut,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  user
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

...

export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    this.user$ = user(this.auth);
  }

  logout(): void {
    signOut(this.auth);
  }

  login(): void {
    signInWithPopup(this.auth, new GoogleAuthProvider);
  }

  async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {

    // only use in code, use observable in template
    return !! await this.user$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }

}
```

J

Comment: Still no updated documentation to this date!